# Listen realtime audio of a Twilio call

Tags: twilio-twiml

My requirement is to listen to the ongoing `Twilio` Call without joining the `Conferance`.

I tried using `<Stream url="wss://your-websocket-endpoint" />` within `<connect>` verb and the using the statuscallback attribute with a url, the only response I get is stop message and a stream id. I have used the following code.

```js
<Connect>
    <Stream url="wss://chunderw-vpc-gll.twilio.com/signal" statusCallback="https://lbwr.operative.dev/multitenant/public/api/streamWebhook" />

</Connect>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether this doesn't violate any law you'd have to adhere to? Doesn't really strike me as legit to eavesdrop on conferences.

Comment: Any calls from telemarketers would have that.It's NOT eavesdropping on a conference.We are monitoring what the agent is doing

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a [Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference), that is what they are made for. A Conference can be just two people most of the time. No way to have a third person (the listener) without using the Conference feature. A Conference is just two or more Voicecalls and you can add more calls and keep them muted so the other callers do not hear them.

If you want to use Stream then your Twiml doesn't match the [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream?code-sample=code-start-a-mediastream&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x) which is missing the Start verb: Try:

```
<Response>
    <Start>
        <Stream name="Example Audio Stream" url="wss://mystream.ngrok.io/audiostream" />
    </Start>
</Response>
```

It will take a fair bit of effort to listen to a websocket stream and less effort to [join](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference?code-sample=code-a-simple-conference&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x) to a Conference in the "supervisor" web browser using the [Javascript client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript) or by dialing in using a phone line.